# Is this a dahlia?

Tags: identification, flowers, bulbs

I salvaged this plant from a dump nearby, because it looked alive. First i thought it was chrysanthemum, but then i noticed the bulbs (don't think chrysanthemums are bulbous). It seems to had been kept in a pot (are dahlias sold/kept in a pot?).

All the flowers and leaves were dead/dried off (either insufficiently watered in the pot, or the frost took them). Flowers were similar to chrysanthemum (filled, colored), but in hindsight they were not unlike dahlia flowers.

What is this? Wanted to plant it out, but if it's dahlia, i have to wait until spring.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a dahlia to me. And yes, they're often sold in pots, particularly in northern areas of the US. In fact, I overwinter two of them in their pots every year, changing out the soil-less mix just before I wake them up in the spring.

Comment: The necks of the tubers are delicate.

Comment: Yep. I wouldn't separate it at all until maybe in the spring. I generally don't separate mine, though.